# Search bar with three inputs, not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to create the same search bar from this site [here](http://demo.templatetrip.com/Opencart/OPC02/OPC040/OPC05/).

As you can see, there is an input field where the user will type whatever he is searching for. Then there is a dropdown with some options. And finally there is a search button.  Since I need to recreate this, I scrapped the `html` and `css` code, but have not achieved the same result.  In my case, I can't get rid of the dropdown default border. I've reached a dead road and can't figure out how to solve this.

The other thing I can't figure out, is that in that site's `css` they have `font-family: 'fontawesome';`. I have never used font awesome like that. I always use `fa fa-icon` in the `html` file.

[image: This is what my search bar is looking like.]

```css
.header-middle {
  margin: 30px auto;
}

#header-search>.form-control.input-lg {
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-right: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #888888;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 300px;
}

.select-wrapper {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 155px;
  height: 38px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.select-wrapper::before {
  border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  content: '';
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  top: 6px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.header-middle .input-group .form-control .inner-search {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 7px 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666666;
}

#header-search .select-wrapper::after {
  content: '\f107';
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  left: auto;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #666666;
}

.select-wrapper::after {
  content: '\f107';
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 6px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#header-search span.input-group-btn {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

.header-middle #header-search .btn-default {
  background: #111111;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 13px 25px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-transform:
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-7 header-middle">
  <div id="header-search" class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" value placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
      <select name="category_id" class="form-control inner-search">
        <option value="0">Categories</option>
        <option value="20">Grocery</option>
        <option value="28">Laptops</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg header-search-btn">
        Buscar
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you want to achieve can be done with `appearance` property set to `none`. The rest are purely stylistic choices to match your desired look.

The two major changes I made are the two top classes in the snippet below.

Bootstrap was interfering with your copied styles. Make sure you pay attention to [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

As for `fontawesome`, you can't add `fa fa-icon` classes to a `pseudo` element, so this is how you do it. You manually assign font family and you use the `content` property to select a glyph.

```css
#header-search select {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

#header-search button {
  border-radius: 0 .3rem .3rem 0;
}

.header-middle {
  margin: 30px auto;
}

#header-search>.form-control.input-lg {
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-right: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #888888;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 300px;
}

.select-wrapper {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 155px;
  height: 38px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.select-wrapper::before {
  border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  content: '';
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  top: 4px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.header-middle .input-group .form-control .inner-search {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 7px 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666666;
}

#header-search .select-wrapper::after {
  content: '\f107';
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  left: auto;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #666666;
}

.select-wrapper::after {
  content: '\f107';
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 6px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#header-search span.input-group-btn {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

.header-middle #header-search .btn-default {
  background: #111111;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 13px 25px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-transform:
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-7 header-middle">
  <div id="header-search" class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" value placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
      <select name="category_id" class="form-control inner-search">
        <option value="0">Categories</option>
        <option value="20">Grocery</option>
        <option value="28">Laptops</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg header-search-btn">
           Buscar
       </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```